# HTTP to HTTPS in IBMIHS in websphere

Tags: websphere, http-redirect

I have a httpd.conf:

```
 .....
    Listen eagnmnmed338:9080
    Listen eagnmnmed338:9443
    .....
    LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
    .....
    <VirtualHost eagnmnmed338:9080>
          RewriteEngine On
          # Disable Trace and Track
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
          RewriteRule .* - [F]

          # restrict to HTTP 1.1
          RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !HTTP/1\.1$
          RewriteRule .* - [F]

    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost eagnmnmed338:9443>
          .....
    </VirtualHost>

.....
```

it works both for http and https.

I need to redirect http requests to https.

I add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =9080
RewriteRule ^http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{SERVER_PORT}%{REQUEST_URI} https://%{SERVER_NAME}:9443/%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

before the virtual host on 9080 definition in global scope.

it does not redirect.

I also add

```
RewriteRule ^http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{SERVER_PORT}%{REQUEST_URI} https://%{SERVER_NAME}:9443/%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

within the block of 9080 def, but it does not work.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

**Some background: an http (port 80) request will goes to a netsscaler first, the netscaler will direct the request to the hosts as  load balance on 9080.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of the RewriteRule matches against the path component of the request URL only, not the entire URL.

Since you already have two virtual hosts, there's no need to check the port or anything else about the request anyway.

Simply within the non-SSL vhost:

```
RewriteEngine ON
# Extract the host w/o a port
RewriteCond ^([^:]+) %{HTTP_HOST}
# Note: 9443 may be unnecessary if the client is using canonical ports.
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%1:9443/$1 [R]
```

Comment: @convener I made the change as you suggested, it does not redirect. I log the rewrite to a file. The message is `56.0.35.6 - - [25/Sep/2019:17:50:59 --0500] [56.42.65.99/sid#5e8008][rid#900c78/initial] (1) escaping https://56.42.65.99:9080:9443/ for redirect <br>
56.0.35.6 - - [25/Sep/2019:17:50:59 --0500] [56.42.65.99/sid#5e8008][rid#900c78/initial] (1) redirect to https://56.42.65.99:9080:9443/ [REDIRECT/302]`. apparently, HTTP_HOST has :9080 trailing.

Comment: Ah yes, answer edited to show extracting it properly with a rewritecond

Comment: No it does not work. Now I get Page can't be displayed, and the rewrite log has: _init rewrite engine with requested uri /
 applying pattern '.*' to uri '/'
 applying pattern '.*' to uri '/'
 applying pattern '^/(.*)' to uri '/'
 pass through /
init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.html
applying pattern '.*' to uri '/index.html'
applying pattern '.*' to uri '/index.html'
pass through /index.html
_